# Get node value of Parent two level up in XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML as shown in sample below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Model>
  <Part Id="0">
    <Specs>
      <Spec Id = "100" name="SpecNode">
      </Spec>
    </Specs>
  </Part>
</Model>
```

This is an sample illustration of XML I have , so pls ignore any typing errors.

So in this XML I was able to retrieve Spec as XPathNodeIterator object. So now I would like to go for Part node and get Id attribute value of it. for what I have is XPathNodeIterator object which points to Spec and Part node lies two level above.

So please guide me in code changes I shall do to achieve this requirement.

Her is my code snippet..

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument("my.xml");
XPathNavigator xmlNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodes = xmlNav.Select(XPathExpression.Compile(@"//Part/Specs/Spec[@name="SpecNode"]))
```

Above code sample gives me nodes object. SO my requirement now is to get Id value of Part node which two level above it.

Comment: Maybe post the code you used...?

Comment: We're going to need your current code if you want us to make changes to it. I can already say that XPathNodeIterator is probably not wat you want to use for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added code snippet as asked.

Comment: What node or value do you actually want to retrieve?

Comment: Part Node and it Id value.

Comment: Both my solution and the one from @DGibbs should work for you. Do you have any more questions?

Comment: Yes , I basically want to retrieve this information using existing "nodes" object. This is an additional request in already working application. So extensive code change is not desirable. What do you this is it possible?

Comment: You do know your code-snippet doesn't even compile, do you?

Comment: snippet was written taking piece of code so having compile errors is possible , added some edits. It should compile now. I think I can expect answer now.

Comment: I have edited my answer, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following LINQ to retrieve the `Id-attribute` of the `Part-node`:

```
const string file = @"D:\Temp\file.xml";

// Load the file.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

// Retrieve the attribute selecting the Part-Element and then its Id-attribute.
XAttribute partAttribute = doc.Root.Descendants("Part").Select(element => element.Attribute("Id")).FirstOrDefault();

// Call partAttribute.Value to retrieve its' value.
Console.WriteLine(partAttribute.Value);
Console.Read();
```

Output: 0.

Do note that if the Part-Element does not exist, a NullReferenceException will be thrown on the partAttribute.Value call. The same happens if the Part-Element exists but the Id does not. Use `if(partAttribute != null)` to make sure if the value exists.

---

If you will be getting alot of Part-nodes, you could sort them on ID using KeyValuePairs:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, XElement>> partNodesWithIDValue = new List<KeyValuePair<int, XElement>>();

// Get a list of all Part-nodes where an ID exists.
List<XElement> partNodes = doc.Root.Descendants("Part").Where(element => element.Attribute("Id") != null).ToList();

// Sort the XElements according to their ID-value.
foreach (XElement partNode in partNodes)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, XElement> elementWithAttribID = new KeyValuePair<int, XElement>(int.Parse(partNode.Attribute("Id").Value), partNode);
    partNodesWithIDValue.Add(elementWithAttribID);
}

// Get a list of all Part-elements where the ID = 1.
List<XElement> partNodesWithID1 = partNodesWithIDValue.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == 1).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

---

Seeing as you want to keep your original code, a simple change of XPath does the trick:

```
XPathNodeIterator nodes = xmlNav.Select(XPathExpression.Compile(@"//Part[@Id]"));
```

`//Part[@Id]`: `//Part` selects all nodes that are named `Part`. Adding the `[@Id]` makes it only select those Part-nodes that have an `Id-attribute.`

Comment: This works but only for the sample - what happens when there are many `Part` nodes (which looks possible else why have an `Id` attribute)?

Comment: @dtsg: Edited accordingly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize the XML to an object, it'll be easier to work with and produces cleaner code:

Model class:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Model
{
    private ModelPart[] partField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Part")]
    public ModelPart[] Part
    {
        get
        {
            return this.partField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.partField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ModelPart
{
    private ModelPartSpecs specsField;
    private byte idField;

    public ModelPartSpecs Specs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.specsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.specsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ModelPartSpecs
{
    private ModelPartSpecsSpec specField;

    public ModelPartSpecsSpec Spec
    {
        get
        {
            return this.specField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.specField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ModelPartSpecsSpec
{
    private byte idField;
    private string nameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));
Model model = null;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml"))
{
      model = (Model)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Now you'll be able to access `model` as an object and accessing the `Part` node is as simple as doing:

```
model.Part
```